# executing xls with macro fails to error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

The file exists, opening workbook works but Application.run gives 1004

```
Set wbtarget = Workbooks.Open(mypath + "\launcher.xls")
Application.Run (wbtarget.Name & "!StartMerge")
```

Comment: 1) wbtarget.name will always return "launcher.xls"  
2) this seems to apply only to macros inold macro sheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work if the StartMerge macro is in a module, but I suspect it is in the worksheet code. If this is the case, try adding the sheet name where the macro is, e.g.

```
Application.Run (wbtarget.Name & "!Sheet1.StartMerge")
```